# How does this website render images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am writing a user script for youtube.com, and want to insert a button with the same look and feel as the other buttons on YouTube page. Things were working in the past, but have suddenly stopped working. 
Have a look at the buttons in this image on top of any youtube video:

[image: YoutubeTopButtons]

So I just noticed one thing in Firebug, these buttons include text and image sub-nodes, but are not rendering the images as simple as giving a source image url to them. The 'src' attribute of these images (the 'plus' sign image, or the 'down arrow' image) or all other such images have exactly the same URL (of a 1 x 1 image) : **//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif**. But in the end they are rendered as all these different images. As a result, when I do the same in my buttons, all other CSS properties work fine, but the images are just blank.

I just want to know from html/javascript/css experts -

1. How are they doing this?
2. How to get these finally rendered images through CSS/javascript?

Thanks!

P.S. : 
-In case a moderator wants to close this question saying it is not a programming question, it is. To know how can one achieve this kind of 'undetectable' html image thing, or how can a userscript still fetch that image through javascript/html/css. 
- In case a moderator wants to close this question saying it is too specific (about youtube.com), it is not. It is a general question about HTML, but I have seen implemented only by YouTube so far. I am a novice.

Thanks, 
Piyush

Comment: There are a lot of answers here, but basically all you need to do is give your button a CSS class of `yt-uix-button`. See my answer below.

Comment: GGG, I was already doing that which was working perfectly, which stopped working recently. Hence this question.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, you need to add both `yt-uix-button` and `yt-uix-button-default` as CSS class names. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This technique is called CSS sprites. It is used to reduce the amount of HTTP requests.

Basically, you have only one image with all your icons (thus you only need to load one image from the server). You would use this image as a background image on your element that has a width/height defined to the size of the icon to display and play with the css properties `background-position` to place the background at the top/left of the icon to display in the background image.

So the important parts are to:

- set the image as background
- set a size to your element. As the image is used as a background, it will not implicitly have a size from the image !
- set the background-position rule

YouTube is using the following image: http://s.ytimg.com/yt/imgbin/www-refresh-vflmpZ5kj.png

[image]

The image is 16px/16px sized and the top/left of the "plus" icon is at the position 97px/66px so they use the following background-position values:

```
background-image: url(//s.ytimg.com/yt/imgbin/www-refresh-vflmpZ5kj.png);
background-position-x: -97px;
background-position-y: -66px;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
```

Further reading:

- [CSS Sprites: Image Slicing’s Kiss of Death](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)
- [The mystery of CSS sprites](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/)

Generators:

- [Online CSS Sprites Generator](http://csssprites.com/)

Comment: You can use the command line tool [glue](http://glue.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to make your own sprites easily

Comment: The triangle is however pure CSS using borders. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: Hi Didier, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Now I understand it !! :)

Comment: blackpla9ue, YES! you are right! Thanks for the link as well! Now I can proceed with both of your suggestions! :)

Comment: @treeface how do we do that? :P ... I want to mark two of the comments as answers though.

Comment: Done. Thanks! But it seems there is no concept of 'main' and 'assisting' answer on stack overflow. It doesn't let me select two of them. Never mind.

Answer (score 4):

This technique is called "CSS sprites":

- http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+sprites

They're using [one image with all the backgrounds](http://s.ytimg.com/yt/imgbin/www-refresh-vflmpZ5kj.png), and using CSS to set the height and width of the element and position the background in a way that only part of it is revealed.

In YouTube's case, they appear to be using an 1x1 blank `<img>` and are setting the background image on the `img` tag itself.

Comment: Aah. That's another useful set of information Madmartigan. Thanks very much. Learning is wonderful :)

Answer (score 1):

> I writing a user script for youtube.com, and want to insert a button with the same look and feel as the other buttons on YouTube page.

Just give your button a class of `yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-default` and it will have the same look and feel of the other buttons. I do the same thing in my own YouTube user script.

> Things were working in the past, but have suddenly stopped working.

Yeah, they changed the class names around a bit during the last big update.

Previously the class was just `yt-uix-button` as you pointed out in your comment, now you have to add `yt-uix-button-default` as well.

---

Here's my custom button, just to show it works ;)

[image]

Comment: Hi GGG, Thanks. I also noticed the CSS class names have been changed, but even after changing them it didn't work. I'll try again. I had already been using yt-uix-button.

Comment: @PiyushSoni `class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-default"` works for me, I just tested it. It doesn't work without `yt-uix-button-default` though.

Comment: You are AWESOME! :) Yes, as soon as I added the 'default' thing, it started working as before! Wonderful. Thanks very much :)

Comment: Hi GGG, I would have marked your reply as the answer, because it was you due to whom I could solve my actual problem. But I went back and saw my own question and looks like I framed it as a general question, to which Didier's answer probably suits best for general public's purpose. I hope you won't mind. Thanks again.

Comment: @PiyushSoni whatever you think is best. I think people chose to give general answers because they didn't have a specific answer for you, and they had a chance to make pretty pictures and attract upvotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CSS declaration for that  tag. For example, the like button has this html:

```
<button onclick=";return false;" title="I like this" type="button" class="start yt-uix-tooltip-reverse  yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-default yt-uix-tooltip" id="watch-like" data-button-toggle="true" data-button-action="yt.www.watch.actions.like" role="button" data-tooltip-text="I like this">
    <img class="yt-uix-button-icon yt-uix-button-icon-watch-like" src="//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt="I like this"><span class="yt-uix-button-content">Like </span>
</button>
```

And in the CSS there's a declaration:

```
#watch-actions .yt-uix-button-icon-watch-like {
    background: no-repeat url(//s.ytimg.com/yt/imgbin/www-refresh-vflmpZ5kj.png) -75px -102px;
    width: 13px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

www-refresh-vflmpZ5kj.png is a sprite and the background declaration positions it at -75px and -102px which is the position of the thumbs up icon.

Comment: Thanks treeface, I was actually looking into it and using their own kind of CSS, but now I come to know that besides the yt-uix-button class, I had to use the yt-uix-button-default class as well ! - Something which they changed recently.